# Should i use eventCallback for GTM before redirecting?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I understand that i should use hitCallback or eventCallback before redirecting to an external websites to make sure that the tags got fired before redirecting, but im wondering if i should use them too before redirecting to other page within the same website in the same tab?

also i would appreciate if you can confirm if my below code is correct and will gurantee to send that event before redirecting

```
  var review_url = 'https://google.com'
  setTimeout(redirect_url, 2000);
  var url_redirected = false;
  function redirect_url() {
    if (!url_redirected) {
      url_redirected = true;
      if (review_url !== '') {
        document.location = review_url;
      }
    }
  }
  dataLayer.push({
      'marketplace' : marketplaceUpper,
      'review-source' : review_source,
      'event' : 'CreateReviewClick',
      'eventCallback' : function() {
          redirect_url();
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the right syntax:

```
var targetUrl = "https://www.google.com";
window.dataLayer.push({
  'marketplace' : marketplaceUpper,
  'review-source' : review_source,
  'event' : 'CreateReviewClick',
  'eventCallback' : function() {
    window.location = targetUrl
  },
  'eventTimeout' : 2000
});
```

Comment: Thank Michele, after testing both my code and yours i found that your code has an issue which my code solved it, when the user's browser block the GTM tracking.. maybe by using a plugin or the incognito mode of Firefox then the reirection wont happen... in my code the redirection would happen anyway after 2 seconds and if the callback function get triggered then the redirection would happen instantly without waiting for 2 seconds

Comment: Better solution is this: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/use-eventtimeout-eventcallback/